# Can I `tag` a service in Consul after its `registration`?

Tags: spring-boot, consul

All, We have micro-services developed using SpringBoot+Kotlin. These services are `registered` with Consul using SpringBoot bootstrap configuration. For these services we don't have the version in the bootstrap config to `tag` them with the `version` of code being deployed while they are being `registered`.
Is there a way we can `tag` these services outside of the SpringBoot registration? I don't generate the version of the code while coding the app. It gets generated in the CICD pipeline.

Our SpringBoot - bootstrap config is as below:

```
cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      watch:
        delay: 5000
      discovery:
        prefer-ip-address: true
        health-check-url: http://localhost:8091/actuator/health
        health-check-interval: 30s
        health-check-tls-skip-verify: true
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}
```

We use Chef to deploy the applications. In the recipes I tried to see if there is an option to tag but the Consul documentation for `registering` the services has `-tag` as an option. So I assumed that we have to `tag` the services only while `registering`. Is there an alternate way?